# Need help iterating through an STL list

Tags: c++, stl

I'm currently working on a movie database project using binary search trees. Each node in the tree contains the title of the film, the year the film was made, and a linked list containing the names of all the actors. This information is all read in from a .txt file.

I've created a few functions already, but I've hit a snag. I'm trying to make a function that enables the user to enter a string, which would be the actors first and last name, and then traverse the tree nodes. If the actors name is found in the linked list within a node, the function would print out the title of that film.

I've never used the STL before, so I don't know if accessing an element is that same as if you were to create the list manually, which is why I'm having issues.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

typedef struct treeNode{
    int year;
    string title;
    list<string> actors;
    treeNode* left;
    treeNode* right;

}* treePtr;

treePtr root = NULL;

treePtr fillTree(treePtr p, int y, string t, list<string> a);
void print_titles(treePtr root);
void print_before_year(treePtr root, int key);
void print_actors_movies(???);


int main(){

    ifstream inFile ("movies.txt");
    string x;
    treePtr root = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    if(inFile.is_open()){

        while(getline (inFile, x)){
            if(x == ""){
                continue;
            }
            count++;

            int index = x.find_last_of(" ");
            string title = x.substr(0, index);
            string year = x.substr(index + 2, x.length() - index - 3);

            list<string> actor;
            int counter = 0;

            while(getline(inFile, x)){
                if(x == ""){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    actor.push_back(x);
                }
            }

            root = fillTree(root, atoi(year.c_str()), title, actor);
        }
    }
    int choice;

    do{

        cout <<"\nWelcome to the Movie Store. Would you like to: \n(1)
        See what movies are available? \n(2) Search for an actor? \n(3)
            Search for a year?   \n(4) Search for a movie? \n(0) Exit the Store" << endl;

                cin >> choice;

        switch(choice){
            case 0:
                cout << "Thank you come again." << endl;
                break;
            case 1:
                print_titles(root);
                break;
            case 2:

            case 3:
                int year;
                cout << "Please enter the year you wish to search for: " << endl;
                cin >> year;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Films made before " << year << ":" << endl;
                print_before_year(root, year);
                break;
            case 4:

            default:
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
        }

    } while(choice != 0);

    return 0;
}


treePtr fillTree(treePtr p, int y, string t, list<string> a){
    treePtr n = new treeNode;
    n->year = y;
    n->title = t;
    n->actors = a;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    if(p == NULL){
        p = n;
    }
    else{
        treePtr prev = p;
        treePtr curr = p;
        while(curr != NULL){
            if(curr->year > y){
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->left;
            }
            else{
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->right;
            }
        }
        if(prev->year > y){
            prev->left = n;
        }
        else{
            prev->right = n;
        }


    }

    return p;
}

void print_titles(treePtr root){
    if(root == NULL) return;
    if(root->left) print_titles(root->left);
    cout<<root->title<<endl;
    if(root->right) print_titles(root->right);
}

void print_before_year(treePtr root, int key){

    if(root == NULL) return;
    if(root->left) print_before_year(root->left, key);
    if(root->year < key){
        cout << root->title << endl;
    }
    else return;
    if(root->right) print_before_year(root->right, key);
}

void print_actors_movies(???){

}
```

And here is the .txt file just in case you need it: http://www2.cs.uidaho.edu/~bruceb/cs121/Assignments/movies.txt

Comment: The answer is really still Boost MultiIndex. :-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin why not jQuery?

Comment: "I've never used the STL before" - I can assure you still don't. The STL is dead, we are now using the C++ standard library.

Comment: @H2CO3: because JavaScript is bad, and you should feel bad for mentioning it, even indirectly.

Comment: @jerrycoffin as if Boost was better, huh? :P (dw, I *do* feel bad.)

Comment: The entrails of C are somewhat pervasive in your code, particularly the tree node type. Just how much latitude are you granted for this assignment (i.e. are there any restrictions on the standard library usage that have been placed on your assignment)?

Comment: @WhozCraig My instructor never explicitly said that we can't use the Standard Library, just that he wouldn't be teaching it to us because he doesn't use it.

Comment: @user2690798 that's "nice". change instructor as soon as you can (if you can at all).

Comment: @user2690798 good to know. and for the record, thats the *last* guy you want to tell you how to use C++ in any manner outside academia. Learn the *language* from him; fine. But constructive programming with it? You're better off with some good books. there's a reason the standards committee formalized all these fantastic tools.

Comment: @H2CO3: Boost is terrible -- and still orders of magnitude better than the highest aspirations of JS, not to mention its reality.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Couldn't possibly agree more.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `treeNode` and you want to look for the name `actor`, you can simple use

```
bool hasActor(treeNode const* node, std::string const& name) {
    return node->actors.end()
        != std::find(node->actors.begin(), node->actors.end(), name);
}
```

The function `std::find()` compares the value identified by each position in the range between the `begin` and the `end` to the `value` passed as last argument using `*it == value`. If this expression returns `true` it returns `it`. If there is no position for which this expression return `true`, it returns `end`.

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple breadth-first search and `std::find()`?

```
bool printTitleForActor(Node *root, const std::string &actor)
{
    if (!root)
        return false;

    if (std::find(root->actors.begin(), root->actors.end(), actor) != root->actors.end()) {
        std::cout << root->title << std::endl;
        return true; // only if you want to terminate upon first find
    }

    return printTitleForActor(root->left) || printTitleForActor(root->right);
}
```

Comment: I think he wants *all* the movies an actor is in; not just the first one in the tree. Trivial to change by simply removing the  hard `return true;` and adding it as an or'd included result with the child searches, in case that was the intent. I wouldn't change the function, just a note for the OP.

Comment: Yeah, the note should be more-than sufficient. Thanks.